# If neo4j-shell is deprecated then how do I dump the contents of the database (for backup)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've just been looking into how to backup the database and have found that neo4j-shell -c dump > my-db-dumb.cql looks like a good solution, which exports everything to a cypher query which creates everything when run (a bit like mysqldump for MySQL).

However, according to the official documentation, neo4j-shell has beed deprecated in favour of cypher-shell, and I can't find the equivalent dump function for cypher-shell. Is there one? If not, what should I do instead of neo4j-shell -c dump? Or is there a better way of backing up the database (I have the community edition)? One advantage of the above solution is you don't have to stop the database.

Comment: Which documentation you are reffering? Whats the version of your neo4j?

Comment: If using newer version, refer https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/dump-load/

Comment: I'm using 3.1.1. Do you know if the neo4j-admin dump command is safe to use while the database is running?

Comment: No. It needs to stop the graph before dumping

Comment: The online backup is only available for the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most useful option is to shutdown the data and then take backups using the new `neo4j-admin` command.

If you cannot shutdown the graph, then you can manually copy the "graph.db" directory to someplace else, and then use `neo4j-shell` using the `-path` option on new location. As far as version 3.1.1 is concerned, the neo4j-shell is working perfectly.

Comment: Yes, neo4j-shell seems to do exactly what I want, but whenever I start it (by typing neo4j-shell), it gives me a warning message saying its been deprecated in favour of cypher-shell, so I'm worried it will be removed in a future version and I'd like to use something future-proof. Ideally I don't want to shut down the database. I'm not sure about copying the folder manually - I think maybe you need to shut down before doing this as well.

Comment: No, only the transactions which have not been committed yet may be missed by manually copying, other than that, it works good. When neo4j is running it creates some extra files in data folder, but they usually dont interfere when copying and starting another instance

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to mark this as the answer, although I still don't think it's a very satisfactory solution. I think that I might write a little script to export the all the nodes and relationships (with labels) as JSON and write another little script to import it.

Comment: Well as I told you earlier, online backup support is only available for enterprise edition. While using scripts make sure you also dump any indexes or constraints in place.

Comment: Trying to work with a very small budget! Thanks for the reminder about indexes/constraints. These aren't so critical though as I have a migrate script which creates them.

Comment: Yes. I am also sticking with 2.2.5 as of now. Because I have developed java based import and export scripts using embedded and REST api and each new version does some changes in cypher and/or apis.